# What kind of function would I have to use in this question?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a question something like this:

Write a program to allocate and display Block and Floor No on the basis of Customer Number. Assuming there are 10 Blocks (‘A’ to ‘J’) with 5 floors (0 to 4) each and allocated to customers sequentially as per their Customer Number. For example Customer no 1 gets [Block A Floor 0], Customer no 3 gets [Block A Floor 2], Customer no 7 gets [Block B Floor 1]
Note: This program has to be done only using arithmetic operations and type conversions (i.e., without the use of if-else) 
Hint: ASCII codes for ‘A’,’B’.. are 65,66,... & chr(65) in python is ‘A’

I have tried this program:

```
Customer = int(input("Customer number : "))
X = (Customer - 1 % 5)
Y = (Customer // 5) 
Z = Y + 65
print("\n\nYour Floor Will Be: ",X)
print("Your Block Will Be: ",chr(Z))
```

Can someone please just tell what Have I Done Wrong? If possible, please also tell The Right answer.
I am currently in 11th Grade and have just started learning Python.
I know most of the Basic functions

Comment: You would need to write a custom function

Comment: You are more likely to get a response for homework-related questions if you at least show the code of what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

just put a bracket
X = ((Customer - 1) % 5)
because acc to sequence of operations mod function will work first